# Custom Login control C# .net 4

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, asp.net-membership

I have everything set up to where I can call Membership.ValidateUser(user, pass)

I want to use Roles. Which is setup. I know that I can do Roles.CreateRole() and such.

The problem is. I need to be able to call User.IsInRole
I don't know how to custom populate the user object by authentication. I Googled the crap outa this and was hoping someone could help. I want to build my own login stuff and not use the built in login control.

Comment: Custom membership provider or just custom login? If custom login, I need more context to why you are having an issue, as the standard membership provider fills the user object when you use the standard calls. If custom, you are missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the look of login contol. Move control to the form, open the smart tag, click "Convert to template" link button. You can set up any layout and style but do not edit ids of inner controls (username, password etc)

UPDATE
If you do not want to use build in login control, you can do all stuff manually. Below are some samples

```
//Use Membership.CreateUser to create new user 
            var newUser = Membership.CreateUser("username", "password");
            //Here is the sample of adding new use to role
            Roles.AddUserToRole("username", "role to add");
            //Remove user from role
            Roles.RemoveUserFromRole("username", "role to remove");
```

Comment: I want to build my own login control and not use the built in one.

Comment: ok, so what do you want to know? how to create user, get current user or something else?

Comment: I know how to call Membership.ValidateUser()

Comment: I want to know how to populate the user object with the roles of that user